# Regex : match ass \fn font tag

Tags: regex

I want to match all `\fn` tags with the following font name, so for :

```
\fnArial\i1

\fnArial

\b1\fnArial)

\t(\fnJester (BIG))

\t(\fnJester (BIG))\i1

\t(\fnJester (BIG)

\t(200,400,20,\i1\blur2\b1 \fnArial)\fnArial (BOLD)\i1\blur2\b1\fnArial\b1
```

I want to match :

> Arial
>
> Arial (BOLD)
>
> Jester (BIG)

Like that without any more bracket or anything else.

The font name is either followed by a `\` or a `)` or end on string (`$`)

My main issue is that there are fonts that end with a bracket like Jester (BIG) and I struggle to match these along with font name that end with a bracket because of a previous `\t(` tag.

I managed to do this, but it's not working for double brackets.

```
(?<=fn)(.*?)(?=\\|(?<=\))(?=\))|(?<=\w)(?=$)(?<=\w)(?=$)|\)$)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I found the right expression :

```
(?<=\\\s*fn).*?(?=\\|(?<=\(.*?\)|\)))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).